# RealTek sound driver

Tags: drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. As compared to Windows 8.1, the sound was very low even with 100% volume level. So, I downloaded RealTek driver and compiled it. Now, my sound card isn't even detected! I did some Google searches and followed those steps but still there is no sound at all. Only dummy output is there. Please help.

Comment: http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and check this file:

```
cat /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

If you find `RUN=yes` then change it to `RUN=no`. This should recover back the sound. However, if the `RUN` is already set to n`o` then upgrading your sound drivers could fix the *no sound* issue:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I did as you said, but still no sound.

Comment: I advice you to read and follow the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) which includes several solutions. Try them one by one and if by the end no solution fits you come back to edit your question with what you experienced again

Comment: Already did that but did it again. Still no sound.